# Why do Len and VBA.Len return different results?

Tags: vba, excel

When I run the following macro:

```
Sub try()
    Dim num As Integer
    num = 123
    MsgBox Len(num)
    MsgBox VBA.Len(num)
End Sub
```

The first `Msgbox` displays `2` and the second `Msgbox` displays `3`.
If I remove the first line which says `Dim num As Integer`, both MsgBoxes display `3`.

Can anyone explain why?

Answer (score 9):

`Len` and `LenB` are not just ordinary functions, they are keywords, and as such are found on the [list of VBA keywords](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/keywords-visual-basic-for-applications) (although `LenB` is only mentioned after you click through to `Len`).
`Mid` would be another example of such keyword disguised as function, whereas e.g. `Left` isn't on the list at all, because that is just an ordinary function.

It has to be a keyword because one of its jobs is to perform the compile-time task of determining the storage size of a variable. E.g. with private user-defined types, an ordinary function could not do that at all:

```vb
Private Type foo
    a As Long
    b As String
End Type

Sub TestLens()
    Dim f As foo
  
    MsgBox Len(f)     ' OK
    MsgBox VBA.Len(f) ' Compile time error
End Sub
```

The fact that the object browser brings you to `VBA.Len` when you press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> on that `Len(f)` is both correct and misleading.
The `Len(f)` here does not actually call the `VBA.Len` function that determines the string size, it simply cannot do that because it would require coercing a private struct into a `Variant`. Instead it calculates the size of `foo` at compile time and substitutes the result as a literal constant into the executable.

In your example the `Len(num)` calculates the compile-time size of *variable `num`* (which is 2) and substitutes the constant `2` into the resulting object code, whereas `VBA.Len(num)` packs the *value of `num`* into a `Variant` and passes that variant to `VBA.Len` where it's further converted to string `"123"` and the length of that is returned.

Comment: `VBA.Len(num) packs the value of num into a Variant and passes that variant to VBA.Len` - Makes my head hurt. It feels like there is some implication of recursion or two calls. I understand the overarching explanation but am stuck on this particular wording.

Comment: @QHarr "The use of expression `VBA.Len(num)` in your code means 'Pack `num` into Variant and pass it to the `VBA.Len` function'".

Comment: It is worth noting that VBE colors the two Len the same, ie not as keywords. Bug?
See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72606203/len-keyboard-not-colored-as-a-keyword-in-vbe

Answer (score 8):

It has to do with the way that VB stores integers and how the `Len()` function handles arguments that are not strings.

When a datatype that is not a string is passed to the `Len()` function, it returns the nominal number of bytes used to store the data (VB uses 2 bytes to store an integer). See the [documentation for the `Len` function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251657%28v=office.14%29.aspx).

The `Len()` function will automatically cast the variant variable (which is created by assigning a value to a variable without declaring it first) as a string. The return isn't changing because the storage allocation changes (although it does; variants require 16 bytes of storage space, minimum). Since the implicitly declared variable is actually a variant type, VB will automatically change its type based on the situation. In this case, `Len()` expects a string so VB makes the variable a string.

You could use `Msgbox Len(Cstr(num))` to cast the integer variable as a string before passing it to the `Len` function if your intent is to return the number of characters in your integer value.

Comment: Still not clear to me how this addresses the actual question: Why do `Len` and `VBA.Len` return different results?

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I'm still left with my original question which is  Why do Len and VBA.Len return different results? (as Jean-François Corbett  above me wrote).

Comment: The new GSerg answer seems the ultimate one, explaining the diff. between Len() and VBA.Len().