# "VBA.len" is 4 times slower than "len" (?!)

Tags: vba

I measured the speed of this code and was surprised by the results after removing the "VBA.":

```
Sub speed_test()
    Dim i As Long, str As String
    'timer_start
    For i = 1 To 1000000
        If VBA.Len(str) = 0 Then  ' vs If Len(str) = 0 Then
        End If
    Next
    'timer_stop
End Sub
```

Using "VBA.Len" it takes 0,040 seconds while using just "Len" it takes 0,010 seconds!

This page [Why do Len and VBA.Len return different results?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29755772/why-do-len-and-vba-len-return-different-results) make me think that it's not just the specification of "VBA." to cause the difference.
It seems more like they are two different functions doing something different.

I get identical 4x speed difference comparing "VBA.LenB" to "LenB"
while I don't see speed difference comparing "VBA.Left$" to "Left$".

How can "VBA.Len" vs "Len" be different?

I always used to add "VBA." in calling internal VBA function as for good practice of specifying the library. Should we abandon this practice after this particular discovery?

Comment: I have posted an answer under your reference question.

Comment: What application is your VBA running in? I suspect that this is in Excel and Len() is calling the worksheet function while VBA.Len() is calling the VBA function.

Comment: @robartsd No, `Len` is not calling any worksheet functions, nor can it.