# Ultimate complete list of native-internal VBA commands

Tags: vba

After discovering (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68507625/vba-len-is-4-times-slower-than-len) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29755772/why-do-len-and-vba-len-return-different-results)) that:

- "VBA.Len" **is not** equivalent to "Len"
- "VBA.LenB" **is not** equivalent to "LenB"
- "VBA.Mid" **is not** equivalent to "Mid"
- "VBA.Left$" **is** equivalent to "Left$"

and other confusing things like that:

- "Left" and "InStr" are in [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/string-manipulation-keyword-summary) official list of keywords while it's not in [this other](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/keywords-visual-basic-for-applications) official list of keywords
- "InStrRev" and "LenB" don't appear in any official keywords lists while "InStr" and "Len" do appear in one or both lists

I'm left very confused about when to use "VBA." and when not.

Is there a way to obtain a **real complete list of the native-internal VBA commands**, more reliable than the official documentation?
I mean something like an "object browser" (where I can see the real complete list of the commands in the "VBA." library) for native-internal VBA commands?

Answer (score 0):

The best resource is probably VBE's help and similar [on-line](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/keywords-by-task), though it's not complete, and doesn't go into the details your raise. Also it doesn't document 'hidden' methods which were once intended to be deprecated but never were, some of which are very useful! Some of your questions were well answered in those other threads, but more generally about your points -

Qualifying with VBA is more about 'where' the method is sourced, and then whether or not there is any difference in the actual method, which in most cases there isn't apart from sourcing. Most of those strings functions are both in the Strings module and in the _HiddenInterface Interface (which is faster).

Left$ though is only in the Strings module, as are similar $ functions, and why you don't notice any difference in performance. Str is both in the _HiddenInterface and Conversion module.

If you're sure the unqualified versions do what you want you might think best to not to qualify, and generally that's fine. But if you ever end up with a project with a MISSING reference, unqualified Strings and DateTime functions will blow before your code has a chance to be alerted. Depending on how deployed or if not sure I tend to fully qualify, eg VBA.Strings.Left$, VBA.DateTime.Date. FWIW as a small bonus you'll get the intellisense.

Comment: Is it possible to explore this _HiddenInterface interface?

Comment: I used the TLBInfo32.dll aka 'TypeLib Information' bundled with VB6. Obviously it's no longer available from MS but it seems to be widely available. Note as an aX it'll only work with 32bit VB/A. From memory there was no documentation so need to dig into it! Handy tool though.

Comment: The _HiddenInterface only seems to expose 27 Key names from Chr to UCase, And curiously with no details of what arguments they take, unlike equivalents in normal modules (libraries) which return same as you see in Object Browser.