# Caveat of not using "VBA." for standard functions

Tags: excel, vba

Is there any reason one would write `VBA.Replace()`, `VBA.Instr()` instead of just `Replace()`, `Instr()` when using these standard functions in VBA?

The only reason I can think of is when you declared functions with the same name in a custom module and you want to differentiate between them.

Edit: This example is answered, thanks to the link provided below (in short Len() is a keyword, not just a function). The example was bad since Len() is an exception.
`Debug.Print VBA.Len(10)` returns "2" while
`Debug.Print Len(10)` throws an error.

The original question remains, is there any caveat of not using the `VBA.` every time?

Comment: This may help - https://stackoverflow.com/a/68507890/15597936

Comment: thanks, that is a pretty helpful link, though I think I just had the wrong example where there actually is a difference. According to the provided list of VBA-keywords Len() is the only function where there definitily is a difference, so the original question remains. I edited my question accordingly.

Comment: I'm certainly not an expert in VBA (even more so when it comes to the technical stuffs) but as far as I know, most of them have no difference and I personally don't use `VBA.` @JohnDoe

Answer (score 1):

You basically answered your own question: If you create a public method with the same name as a VBA method, it takes precedence over the VBA one. E.g. put this one in a module:

```
'------------------------------------------------------------------------------
'Purpose  : Override the VBA.CreateObject function in order to register what object
'           is being created in any error message that's generated.
'
'   Author: Darin Higgins
'   Source: http://www.darinhiggins.com/the-vb6-createobject-function/
'------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Public Function CreateObject(ByVal sClass As String, _
   Optional ByVal sServerName As String = vbNullString _
   ) As Object
   
   Dim sSource As String, sDescr As String, lErrNum As Long
   
   On Error Resume Next
   
   If Len(sServerName) Then
      Set CreateObject = VBA.CreateObject(sClass, sServerName)
   Else
      Set CreateObject = VBA.CreateObject(sClass)
   End If
   
   If VBA.Err Then
      sSource = VBA.Err.Source
      sDescr = VBA.Err.Description
      lErrNum = VBA.Err
      sDescr = sDescr & " (ProgID: " & sClass
      If Len(sServerName) Then
         sDescr = sDescr & ". Instantiated on Server '" & sServerName & "'"
      End If
      sDescr = sDescr & ")"
      
      On Error GoTo 0
      
      VBA.Err.Raise lErrNum, sSource, sDescr
   End If
   
   On Error GoTo 0
   
End Function
```

Steping through the code `Set x = CreateObject("Object.Class")` will step into this function instead of VBA.CreateObject.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer! I was just wondering whether there might be any other reason, but then I guess there isn't.