# Integer value wont update in a vba (excel) sub

Tags: excel, vba

Im using Visual Basic for Applications. I have an excel column filled with a long list of products and a number at the end. Im trying to create a procedure that erases the number and leave just the product names. It works fine until reaching the 99, but form 100, it just erases the last two digits, converting strings like "SCION 100" in "SCION 1", "SEAT 101" in "SEAT 1", and so on. The reason is that my integer named 'paginationLength' does not update even if i specifically write it in my code.

Here is what the list looks like

- SC1 98

  SC2 98

  SL 98

  SL1 99

  SL2 99

  SW1 99

  SW2 99

  SCION 100

  XD 100

  SEAT 101

  CORDOBA 101

  IBIZA 101

Here is my full code

```
Sub quitarPaginacion2()
    Dim sheet As String
    Dim column As String
    Dim numRows As Integer
    Dim startPagination As Integer
    Dim paginationLength As Integer
    Dim value As String
    Dim valueLength As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    
    sheet = "Hoja2"
    column = "A"
    numRows = Worksheets(sheet).UsedRange.Rows.Count
    startPagination = 12 '12 is the first number i want to erase and
                          'it increments during the excecution
    paginationLength = Len(startPagination)
    
    For i = 1 To numRows
        value = Worksheets(sheet).Range(column & i)
        valueLength = Len(value)
        
        If Right(value, paginationLength) <> startPagination Then
            startPagination = startPagination + 1
            paginationLength = Len(startPagination) ' <-----Here. When 'startPagination' reaches 100,              
                                                    '  Len(startPagination) returns '3' butpaginationLength stays '2'
        End If
        
        Worksheets(sheet).Range(column & i) = Left(value, valueLength - paginationLength)
        
    Next
End Sub
```

I also tried this

```
Function inc(data As Integer) As Integer
    data = data + 1
    inc = data
End Function

startPagination = inc(startPagination)
paginationLength = Len(startPagination)
```

Comment: Read up on the VBA split function.

Comment: Thank you, it will surely work to archieve what im tying to do. But i would like to know why my code wasnt working. Even if it is unnecessary complicated, i think is should work.

Comment: The `Len` of an `Integer` is [always](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29755772/why-do-len-and-vba-len-return-different-results) 2. You want `VBA.Len`.

Comment: When posting question you are supposed to make it as easy as possible for SO colleagues to read your code and understand the problem.  You say your are trying to trim the numbers from the end of a string, but your code is about pagination.  That's very confusing.

Comment: Thats the answer i was looking for. Thank you!. Sorry for the duplicated question.

Comment: Im sorry, I thought it would be helpful to give you the full context. I'll try to make it simple in the future.